# Text File in R not loading all the text in R

Tags: r, text, readr

When I upload a file a text file into R the text is being truncated and i cant get an accurate count. Is there another command I should use so I the entire text file is read.

```
library(stringr)
> readr::read_file("Apple_Wikipedia.txt")
[1] "Apple Inc. is an American multinational technology company headquartered in Cupertino, California that designs, develops, and sells consumer electronics, computer software, and online services. The company's hardware products include the iPhone smartphone, the iPad tablet computer, the Mac personal computer, the iPod portable media player, the Apple Watch smartwatch, the Apple TV digital media player, and the HomePod smart speaker. Apple's consumer software includes the macOS and iOS operating systems, the iTunes media player, the Safari web browser, and the iLife and iWork creativity and productivity suites. Its online services include the iTunes Store, the iOS App Store and Mac App Store, Apple Music, and iCloud.\r\nApple was founded by Steve Jobs, Steve Wozniak, and Ronald Wayne in April 1976 to develop and sell personal computers. It was incorporated as Apple Computer, Inc. in January 1977, and sales of its computers saw significant momentum and revenue growth for the company.... <truncated>
> x <- c("Apple","ios", "iphone")
> str_count(x)
[1] 5 3 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need assign the text to an actual object in R. Currently you are just reading in the text without saving it anywhere and then calling `str_count` in an inappropriate fashion, so it's just returning the number of characters in 'Apple'(5), 'ios'(3) and 'iphone'(6). The display of the text in the R console will still be truncated at some point, but the data will be fully saved. The following should work.

```
    library(stringr)    
    apple_wiki <- readr::read_file("Apple_Wikipedia.txt")
    x <- c("Apple","iOS", "iPhone") 
    str_count(apple_wiki, x)
```

Please also be aware that str_count is case-sensitive, so be careful to match your terms with the wiki entry or use regular expressions or text conversions to get around it.